# update() in classserializer not taking input from postman

Tags: django, python-2.7, nested, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have two Models Country and Address,
accordingly I have created two serializers CountrySerializer and AddressSerializer

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='country.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = '__all__'


class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = CountrySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'`


class Country(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.name

class Address(models.Model):
      street_address = models.TextField(default=None)
      country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

Now i want to update AddressSerializer, when i use `PUT` method in Postman with field country it doesn't take an input, instead it updates existing country and not new input, can anyone help me in this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: why did u keep country as readonlyfield in CountrySerializer ?

Comment: if i remove that only id is shown in my Json

Comment: @sourabhah can you update your question with views and  models

Comment: @sourabhah can you please check if you can update street_address with existing country ?

Comment: @Darshan yes i can update street_address but Country is not updated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new record, you should use `POST` method instead.

Comment: Seems like i misunderstood question. You want to update your Address serializer, you put data into it, but instead of using input data, it updates by what?

Comment: It updates with AddressSerializer data, but not CountrySerializer

Comment: [link]http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/                                as given above link i use instance.country but it gives me existing country.

Comment: perhaps, as was told in first comment to your question, problem in country field that it is ReadOnly?